# WPF / C# Using variables in API POST

Tags: c#, api, post

Following on from the following question

[WPF / C# Submit button to POST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74432056/wpf-c-sharp-submit-button-to-post-api/74444272?noredirect=1#comment131420449_74444272)

I now want to amend the POST BODY to include Username and Password Variable.

The below is what I am using at the moment

```
var OktaUserName = ADAccountName;
var OktaPassword = Password;

var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://trial.okta.com/api/v1/authn");

request.Content = new StringContent("{\"username\":"+OktaUserName+",\"password\":"+OktaPassword+",\"options\": {\"multiOptionalFactorEnroll\": true,\"warnBeforePasswordExpired\": true}}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
MessageBox.Show("Alert", json, "OK");
MessageBox.Show(responseContent, "Message");
```

I expect that the username and password is pulled from the stored variables and then added to OKTA as a new user, however with the above I get an error

`ErrorCode E000003 Error Summary The Request Body was not well-formed`

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your content string values are missing "

Comment: If you mean the ADAccountName and Password strings, they are used in the code above (not shown). 
Even if I replace the variables with a text string such as 

var OktaUserName = "Name";
var OktaPassword = "password123";

I still get the same error

Comment: The are missing a pair of " each. Take a look at the string as it goes into the content.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Fildor, your answers helped.

My modified request.Content is as follows

```
request.Content = new StringContent("{\"username\":\""+ADAccountNameStr+"\",\"password\":\""+PasswordStr+"\",\"options\": {\"multiOptionalFactorEnroll\": true,\"warnBeforePasswordExpired\": true}}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```